# Set Background Image for RectangleGeometry in WPF?

Tags: wpf, image, background, rectangles

I have this code:

```
<Path Fill="Brown">
  <Path.Data>
    <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rec"
                       RadiusX="0"
                       RadiusY="20"
                       Rect="410,135,60,25"></RectangleGeometry>
  </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

How can I set the background `Image` for this `Rectangle`?

Comment: Hi! When asking a question on Stackoverflow you should give as much detail about your problem as possible: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice.

Answer (score 1):

You may to use an [`ImageBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms619168.aspx) for the Path's `Fill` property:

```
<Path>
    <Path.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="..."/>
    </Path.Fill>
    <Path.Data>
        <RectangleGeometry x:Name="rec" RadiusX="0" RadiusY="20" Rect="410,135,60,25"></RectangleGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```